# How to check if object is const or not?

Tags: c++

My problem is that I have no idea how to check if object is const. I can only use C++98. How can I check if object have const modifier? How to overload functions properly?

```
int main(){
  Vec x;
  const Vec y;

  cout<<"Is x const? ";
  y.IfConst(x);     // cout << "no"
  cout<<"\n";

  cout<<"Is x const? ";
  x.IfConst(x)      // cout << "no"
  cout<<"\n";

  cout<<"Is y const? ";
  x.IfConst(y);     // cout << "yes"
  cout<<"\n";

  cout<<"Is y const? ";
  y.IfConst(y);     // cout << "yes"
  cout<<"\n";
  /**/
}
```

I need output look like:
is x const? no
is x const? no
is y const? yes
is y const? yes

I used:

```
void Vec::IsConst(Vec const &vecc) const{
  std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;      
}

void Vec::IsConst(Vec const &vecc) {
  std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;       
}
```

Comment: constness is a compile-time property

Comment: Why do you want to detect const-ness at run time? It sounds like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I need that. Thanks for help.

    void Vec(Vec const &Vecc) const{
    std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;   
    }

    void Vec(Vec const&Vecc){          
    std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;   
    }

    void Vec(Vec &Vecc) const {
    std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;  
    }

    void Vec(Vec &Vecc) {
    std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;  
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve my problem i needed to overload functions

```
void Vec(Vec const &Vecc) const{
std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;            
}

void Vec(Vec const&Vecc){                        
std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;            
}

void Vec(Vec &Vecc) const {
std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;     
}

void Vec(Vec &Vecc) {
std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;     
}
```

Answer (score 13):

constness is known and used only as compile time, the information doesn't exist at runtime, it has no sense.

However, at compile time, if you have a C++11 compliant compiler, you can use the standard `std::is_const` [type trait](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const) on a type:

```
int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_const<const int>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_const<Vec>::value  << '\n';
}
```

If you don't have a c++11 compiler, you can use [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/boost/type_traits/is_const.hpp) one.

Comment: It's pretty easy to make your own in C++98 if I'm not mistaken. Or use Boost's.

Comment: I added a reference to boost's one, its easy to mimic yes.

Comment: @quantdev The solution is really very simple. No need to rely on `boost` or `C++11` functionality. Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed syntax does not make sense to me.

This works for me.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> bool isConst(T& x)
{
   return false;
}

template <typename T> bool isConst(T const& x)
{
   return true;
}

int main() 
{
   int x;
   const double y = 0.0;

   std::cout << "Is x const? ";
   std::cout << isConst(x) << "\n";

   std::cout << "Is y const? ";
   std::cout << isConst(y) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Is x const? 0
Is y const? 1
```

Comment: Well, doesn't work for references, so I prefer "relying" on the standard library or boost than reinventing the wheel . http://ideone.com/f3r6cu   . So you give me back the downvote ? ;)

Comment: Yes, not working. xx is a const reference to a non const object , still returning true (by the way my example is exactly your code). So your templates are NOT equivalent to the boost/stl ones.

Comment: When looked through `xx`, the object is a `const`. You can't modify it through `xx`

Comment: I think I see what you are saying now. `std::is_const<const int&>::value` is `false`. Hence, `isConst(xx);` should return false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55035/discussion-between-r-sahu-and-quantdev).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check for this at runtime. Since the compiler will throw an error if in the code you try to modify a `const` object.

On the other hand if you decide to do some typecasting/pointer magic to force modification of a const object then there is no way to detect it.

The main reason for the inability to detect is that, unlike interpreted languages like python and java(if you think of JVM as an interpreter), C++ doesn't provide much introspection features. structs and classes simply map their data layout as a block in memory, with no other metadata attached to it. This makes C/C++ the middle level language with higher efficiency and less introspection.