# Why does std::is_const<const int&>::value evaluate to false?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

This is a spin off of the question [How to check if object is const or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028621/how-to-check-if-object-is-const-or-not/24028924#24028924).

I was surprised to see the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main() 
{
   std::cout << std::boolalpha;
   std::cout << std::is_const<const int&>::value << "\n";
}
```

produced this output

```
false
```

In what context does it make sense to think of `const int&` as a non-const type?

Comment: `is_const<T>` is defined as "T is const-qualified". References can't be cv-qualified, so it makes sense from a language perspective.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217453/why-does-boostis-sameint-const-boostadd-constint-value-equal-false?rq=1

Comment: @Mat, would you mind converting your comment to an answer? That seems to contain the best answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps it'll be easier to understand with this example

```
std::cout << std::is_const<int const *>::value << "\n";  // pointer to const int
std::cout << std::is_const<int * const>::value << "\n";  // const pointer to int
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

The first type is a pointer to a `const int`, while in the second the `int *` itself is `const`. Hence it results in `true` while the former is `false`. Similarly, what you have a reference to a `const int`. If `int& const` were valid it'd result in `true`.

Comment: Since a variable of type reference cannot be made to refer to another object after its initialization, it makes more sense for `std::is_const<int&>::value` as well as `std::is_const<const int&>::value` to evaluate to 'true` than `false`.

Comment: @RSahu I don't get why you think that. As I'm sure you understand, the `const` in `int const&` indicates the `int` cannot be modified. The purpose of `is_const` is to indicate whether *T is const-qualified* (quoted from 20.10.4.3). In both cases you've listed `T = int&`; clearly `T` is not `const`. It would be counter-intuitive for it to return `true` in either case.

Comment: I understand that. Perhaps I am finding it hard to justify its specified behavior. It makes more sense to me to think of the const-ness of a reference variable to be the same as the const-ness of the type it references.

Comment: @RSahu I can see where you're coming from, but you'd agree that that sort of *const because the other option is ill-formed* behavior would only apply to reference types. It wouldn't even make sense for cases where `T = U*`. It'd be yet another special case everyone needs to remember.

Comment: Yes. I agree. It would apply only to reference types. Please understand that I am speaking from a language user's point of view. From a language developer's point of view, the behavior of `is_const` perhaps makes more sense.

Answer (score -1):

A `const` qualifier on a reference just means that the value can't be modified *via the reference*.  It can still be modified by other means.  For example:

```
int a = 1;
const int &b = a;

std::cout << b << std::endl;  // Prints 1

a = 2;

std::cout << b << std::endl;  // Prints 2
```

Thus, you can't assume that the value of a `const` reference is actually constant.

Comment: Don't know why this attracted a downvote. It correctly states that the `const` here only applies to the type of expressions involving `b`. Neither `a` nor `b` are `const` themselves. (That said, Praetorian's answer is a lot clearer)

Comment: This is true but nothing to do with the question