# How to write is_reference_const function,make is_reference_const<const int&>::value` is ture

Tags: c++

We see `std::is_const<const int&>::value` is always false.So this instruction  #1 is never execute.

```
template <typename T>  void g(T&& val)
    {
      if(is_const<T>::value)
      {
      #1  if(is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)cout<<"const l reference"<<endl;
          else if(is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)cout<<"const r reference"<<endl;
          else cout<<"const int"<<endl;
      }else
      {
          if(is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)cout<<"l reference"<<endl;
          else if(is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)cout<<" r reference"<<endl;
          else cout<<" int"<<endl;
      }

    }
```

Why STL not provide is_reference_const function for this issue?And Can we write this function for this?
At last, this function such as `is_reference_const<const int&>::value` is ture.

Comment: Feel free to write a proposal. Making your own should be trivial, though. According to your description, you should be able to combine `std::remove_reference` with `std::is_const`.

Comment: Thank you.but if(is_reference<T>::value)
  {
    cout<<"is reference"<<endl;
    if(is_const<remove_reference<T>>::value){cout<<"const reference"<<endl;}
  } does't work.

Comment: I'm not having any problems with the combination of the two.

Comment: Did you mean to do `is_const<typename remove_reference<T>::type>::value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything is in the standard because someone wanted it there and put the energy into getting it there and convinced the committee it was a good idea.

This works:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct is_reference_const
{
        static const bool value = std::is_reference<T>::value && std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value;
};

int main()
{
        std::cout << is_reference_const<const int &>::value << std::endl;
        std::cout << is_reference_const<const int>::value << std::endl;
        std::cout << is_reference_const<int &>::value << std::endl;
        std::cout << is_reference_const<int>::value << std::endl;
}

1
0
0
0
```

I was surprised that `is_const<const int&>::value` was `false`.

Comment: you can see this question [Why does std::is_const<const int&>::value evaluate to false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029723/why-does-stdis-constconst-intvalue-evaluate-to-false)

Comment: Thanke you for your answer.std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value is correct.