# Why is std::is_const::value 'false' even though T's value_type is const?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

```
#include <type_traits>

struct foo;
int main()
{
    const foo *bar;

    static_assert(std::is_const<decltype(*bar)>::value,
                  "expected const but this is non-const!");
}
```

This results in a failing `static_assert` which is unexpected. This is somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24029723/234175) on const references but not quite the same.

In my case, dereferencing `bar` should give an instance of `const foo` as its type but yet `std::is_const` is saying otherwise.

Comment: `const foo *bar` makes a const _pointer_, but the value it points to is _not_ const.

Comment: @Aganju no it doesn't, that's `foo *const bar;`

Comment: `const foo *bar` same as `foo const *bar` But different from `foo *const bar`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Shortly that's because a reference or a pointer to a const type is not a const type.
Note that `decltype(*bar)` isn't `const foo`, it's `const foo &` and they are really different beasts.

---

Consider the example given [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const):

```
std::cout << std::is_const<const int *>::value << '\n'; // false
std::cout << std::is_const<int * const>::value << '\n'; // true
```

We see that `std::is_const<const int *>::value` is false and `std::is_const<int * const>::value` is true.
That's because in `const int *` the type is pointer to something const, that is not a const type as intended by `is_const` (and the standard actually). In `int * const` the const qualifier applies to the pointer type and not to the pointed one, thus the type is a const one, no matter to what it points.
Something similar applies for `const foo &`, that is a reference to something const.

You can solve using this instead:

```
static_assert(std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*bar)>>::value, "expected const but this is non-const!");
```

Or even this, for you don't need to do `*bar` actually:

```
static_assert(std::is_const<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(bar)>>::value, "expected const but this is non-const!");
```

In this case, by *removing the pointer/reference* with `remove_pointer_t`/`remove_reference_t` your type becomes `const foo`, that is actually a const type.

---

As a side note, the example above uses the *C++14-ish* `std::remove_reference_t` and `std::remove_pointer_t` type traits.
You can easily turn those lines of code to C++11 as it follows:

```
static_assert(std::is_const<typename std::remove_pointer<decltype(bar)>:: type>::value, "expected const but this is non-const!");
```

---

It's worth mentioning a few comments to the answer to give more details:

- Thanks to @DanielFischer for the question:

  > Is there a short explanation why `decltype(*bar)` is `const foo&` rather than `const foo`?

  I'm not a language-lawyer, but I guess it can be deduced from [[expr.unary.op]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary#op-1) (emphasis mine):

  > **The unary * operator performs indirection**: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type **and the result is an lvalue** referring to the object or function to which the expression points.

  And [[dcl.type.simple]/4.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4.4) (emphasis mine):

  > otherwise, **if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T&**, where T is the type of e;

  Both referring to the working draft.
- Thanks to @LightnessRacesInOrbit for the comment. Note that `decltype(*bar)` being `const foo &` is a funny C++ quirk of `decltype`, since `*bar` is not `const foo &`.

Comment: Worth mentioning explicitly imo: `decltype(*bar)` isn't `const foo` it is `const foo&`

Comment: @RyanHaining that's good to know, that's the piece I was missing.

Comment: @RyanHaining Added to the first line.

Comment: @RyanHaining Is there a short explanation why `decltype(*bar)` is `const foo&` rather than `const foo`?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not a language-lawyer, but I guess you can deduce it from [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary#op-1) (_The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points._) and [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4.4) (_otherwise, if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T&, where T is the type of e;_) - working draft.

Comment: Thanks, @skypjack. Indeed, with `decltype(e)` being `T&` for lvalues, it's clear.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not adding it to the answer, but let me know if you find that it's worth it.

Comment: _"Note that decltype(*bar) isn't const foo, it's const foo &"_ This in itself is a funny C++ quirk of decltype, since `*bar` is not `const foo&`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit See my comment above. I'm not that sure everything is right, but I tried to get out of the standard the right sections to explain it. The whys behind the choice must be addressed to the working group maybe. :-)

Comment: @skypjack: Yes, your quotes were correct. I just wanted to remind everyone in simple language that dereferencing a pointer doesn't produce a reference ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Probably I should integrate these comments into the answer. It sounds more interesting than what it appeared initially. Would it worth it?

Comment: @skypjack: Certainly!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just done. Thank you for the details. ;-)