# Why does my isVector function not return true?

Tags: c++, constexpr, decltype

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043078/4614680) question, I experimented with a `is_vector` trait:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct is_vector { 
        constexpr static bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T>> { 
        constexpr static bool value = true;
};

int main() { 
    int A;
    vector<int> B;

    cout << "A: " << is_vector<decltype(A)>::value << endl;
    cout << "B: " << is_vector<decltype(B)>::value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A: 0
B: 1
```

This works as expected. However, when I try to put this in a small helper function, `is_vector` returns `false` for `B`:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool isVector(const T& t) { 
        return is_vector<decltype(t)>::value;
}
...
cout << "B: " << isVector(B) << endl;  // Expected ouptput: "B: 1"
```

Output:

```
B: 0
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, `t ` is `const std::vector<int>&`.

Comment: Also thanks to you @BoPersson for the quick response.

Comment: Almost dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996441/why-is-stdis-constvalue-false-even-though-ts-value-type-is-const

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is `t` is a `const std::vector<int>&` which does not match `struct is_vector<std::vector<T>>`.  What you really want in your function is to use `T` which is deduced as `std::vector<T>` which does work.  Doing that you get

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool isVector(const T& t) { 
        return is_vector<T>::value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I feel silly. I'll accept your answer as soon as possible.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig No problem.  Glad to help.